# Nginx: logging on multiple conditions

Tags: nginx, logging, conditional-statements

I am trying to configure nginx/1.13.0 with conditional access_logging.

If access_logging is conditional on the $status code only, everything works fine:

```
http {
     [..]
     map $status $logworthy_status {
         ~^[4]  1;
         default 0;
     }
     [..]
     server {
          [..]
          access_log  /var/log/nginx_access.log combined if=$logworthy_status;
          [..]
     }
}
```

The debug log shows the map behaving as expected:

```
2017/06/13 11:34:14 [debug] 23153#0: *203 http map started
2017/06/13 11:34:14 [debug] 23153#0: *203 http script var: "401"
2017/06/13 11:34:14 [debug] 23153#0: *203 http map: "401" "1"
```

But, if I try to rewrite this to allow more than one condition as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/jrom/1760790%20here):

```
http {
     [..]
     map $status $logworthy_status {
         ~^[4]  1;
         default 0;
     }
     [..]
     server {
          [..]
          set $logworthy 0;
          if ( $logworthy_status = 1 ) {
              set $logworthy 1;
          }
          access_log  /var/log/nginx_access.log  combined if=$logworthy;
          [..]
     }
}
```

no log messages are generated. Checking the debug log shows that even the mapping on $status seems messed up:

```
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 rewrite phase: 0
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script value: "0"
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script set $logworthy
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script var
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http map started
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script var: "000"
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http map: "000" "0"
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script var: "0"
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script value: "1"
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script equal
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script equal: no
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script if
2017/06/13 11:38:12 [debug] 23631#0: *204 http script if: false
```

Can somebody explain this? The request gets processed as expected, nginx returns a 401, yet it does not log this.

Answer (score 11):

You can use multiple [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directives with a default value from previous block. For example, log 4xx status requests where User-Agent does not contain "AppleWebKit"

```
map $status $loggable_status {
    ~^[4]   1;
    default 0;
}
map $http_user_agent $loggable_user_agent {
    ~*AppleWebKit   0;
    default $loggable_status; # Use map var above as default
}

access_log /var/log/nginx/error.log combined if=$loggable_user_agent;
```